# Is it possible getter then operator use in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I want to etr%. The logic of etr% find is subtract(request_Date-xetr) if it is getter then etr then 1 else 0. I want to calculate sucess % in group by my code is

error line: COUNT(case when (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,Request_Date, Xetr) < etr then 1 else 0 end)*100/count(1)) as etr

Comment: 'out of total' among ALL assignedid ?

Comment: yes out of all assignedid. I want to calculate percentage

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `request_date` and `xetr` are DATETIME datatype, and `etr` is TIME datatype...

We could get the difference in *minutes* between the two DATETIME values, and then compare to a number of *minutes* derived from a TIME datatype. (We need to do a conversion, because the comparison of an integer to a TIME datatype is unlikely to yield the result we want.)

It's much more straightforward to use the MySQL `ADDTIME` function. We can add add `etr` (a TIME datatype, an amount of time) to `request_date` (a DATETIME), to return a DATETIME. And we can easily compare that to `xetr` (another DATETIME).

For example:

```
 ADDTIME( request_date , etr ) > xetr
```

---

We should *test* that, and verify the result, before we incorporate that into an aggregate function. Putting that conditional test into the expression, we get:

```
 COUNT(CASE ADDTIME(request_date,etr) > xetr THEN 1 END)/COUNT(1)*100 AS etr
```

---

The parens seem oddly placed, and doesn't appear to be legal. It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve, but I suspect you're looking for the result returned by something like this:

```
  COUNT( CASE
         WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,request_date,xetr) < etr 
         THEN 1
         ELSE NULL
         END 
  ) * 100 / COUNT(1) AS etr
```

---

Also notice that the `ELSE 0` is replaced by `ELSE NULL`. With the zero instead of the NULL, the value returned by CASE is guaranteed to be non-NULL, so every row will be counted, and the value of the entire expression will either be 100 or 0. Replacing the 0 with a NULL seems like it will be closer to what you are attempting to achieve.

---

This is only a guess.

Comment: SELECT Assignedto
,COUNT(Assignedto) as TC
, COUNT( CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,request_date,xetr) < etr
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0
         END
  ) * 100 / COUNT(1) AS etr
FROM `it_service_ticket` INNER JOIN
     `it_problem`
     ON `it_service_ticket`.`it_problem_id`=`it_problem`.`it_problem_id` INNER JOIN
     `city_master`
     ON `it_service_ticket`.cityid=`city_master`.city_id
WHERE `it_service_ticket`.`xetr` BETWEEN '2016-04-01 12:00:00 AM' AND '2017-02-28 12:00:00 PM'
GROUP BY Assignedto;

Comment: sir I want to calculate etr from assignedto. if <etr then 1 and out of total . I want to calculate % of 1(<etr).

Comment: The result from the CASE expression will always be non-NULL, so it's equivalent to COUNT(1), the return from that entire expression will be either 100 or 0. (I think I made this point in my answer. The ELSE 0 needs to be replaced by ELSE NULL)

Comment: None of the column references is qualified. We're only guessing which column references refer to which table. The `etr` reference in the CASE expression seems to be a number of minutes (since it's being compared to a number of minutes. So that must be coming from one of the tables referenced in the FROM clause. It's not possible to reference an alias in the SELECT list within the same SELECT list. And it doesn't make sense that we would want to compare a number of minutes (the result of the TIMESTAMPDIFF function) to a percentage.

Comment: If the goal is to return a percentage of the number of rows where the elapsed time between `request_date` and `xetr` is less than `etr`, vs. the total number of rows, the expression in my answer should do that. If you want to use something else as either the numerator or denominator, we'd need some sort of explanation. Aside from this, I don't understand what you mean by "I want to calculate % of 1(<etr)"

Comment: sir I have one doubts can we compare minutes with hours...like 00:15<01:00

Comment: TIMESTAMPDIFF returns an integer. The query expression is comparing that to a column reference `etr`.  The updated question shows a column named `etr_time`, but that doesn't appear to be an integer. Not at all clear what the *datatype* of the `etr_time` column is, is that a TIME expression, or VARCHAR? In order to compare that to a integer number of minutes, a datatype conversion will be required.

Comment: Sir time data type

Comment: If `etr` is TIME datatype, you could do a comparison if you do some  conversion.  For example, either compare seconds `TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,..,...) < TIME_TO_SEC(etr)`, or, if you want to compare minutes, `TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,...,...) < TIME_TO_SEC(etr_time)/60`. Personally, I'd avoid all that complexity, and do a simpler comparison.  If the difference between datetimes `dt2` and `dt1` is less than time `tm3`, i.e. if `(dt2-dt1)<tm3`, then we know `(dt1+tm3)>dt2` To express that in a MySQL expression...  **`COUNT(CASE WHEN ADDTIME(request_date,etr)>xetr THEN 1 END)`**

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime

Comment: I want to subtract request_Time to xetr (both are datatime) but etr is time which is minutes and hours. sof if I compare minutes with hours. What is result. like 15 minuts<1 hours... true or false?

Comment: If you absolutely need to "subtract" request_time and xetr, then you can  use the `TIMEDIFF` function, which will return a TIME datatype. And you can compare the result from TIMEDIFF with a TIME dataype. But be aware that TIME datatype is bounded, there's maximum value. I'd prefer to avoid that potential pitfall, and instead add a TIME to a DATETIME to get a DATETIME I can compare to another DATETIME.